# Manifest doubts

Tags: windows, winapi, sdk, manifest

I followed the below steps.
1.I am calling 2 exes(b&c) from one exe(a) which are all mingw based.
2.I created 3 seperate manifiest files for a,b,c using `mageui.exe`.
3.Executed the below command for all 3 manifest files and for the corresponding exe's.

```
mt.exe –manifest temp.manifest –outputresource:YourApp.exe;#1
```

My questions:
1. Are the above steps correct?
2. If they are correct, is it required to distribute the manifest files with the exe's?
3. Is it possible to manage with only one manifest file instead of 3 for each exe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to distribute the manifest file at all. By using `mt.exe` you have embedded the manifest into the executable. Use a resource editing tool to confirm that the manifest has indeed been embedded as a Windows resource.

Can you use the same manifest for all executables? That depends on what's in the manifest. If you are specifying `processorArchitecture` then you'd need different manifests if you have both 32 and 64 bit executables. But I think that question is moot since you don't need to distribute the manifests.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.. Its clear.. Hope my steps are correct? Q no (1)?

Comment: I'm not familiar with mingw manifest tools, but it looks OK. Use a resource editor to check the resulting executables.